# python XlsxWriter: How to center view on selected cell?

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

Using python XlsxWriter, I would like to set the active cell and make sure this cell appears on the screen when the user opens the spreadsheet.

```
import xlsxwriter
import os

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook("test_file.xlsx")
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
worksheet.write(99, 0, "I am here!")  # write in A100
worksheet.set_selection(99, 0, 99, 0)  #
workbook.close()
os.startfile("test_file.xlsx")  # to have the file opened in Excel automatically
```

This indeed sets the selected cell to A100, [but the view is still centered on the top of the page when I open the spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfWmt.png). Any idea how I could get the view automatically centered on the selected cell without having to scroll down?

[image]

Thanks in advance !

Comment: That feature isn't currently supported in XlsxWriter.

Comment: https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html  this link can help u